# add css if url contains

Tags: views, theming, forms

I have one node type and two page types for this node.

```
http://site.com/themes/*
```

and

```
http://site.com/years/*
```

And i want to hide one of the "view-filed" in all "years" pages using the css.

Found this but it doesn't work

```
function mythemename_preprocess_page(&$variables,$hook) {
  $alias = explode('/',drupal_get_path_alias(request_uri()));
  if($alias[1]== "years") {
   $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'years';
  }
}
```

https://groups.drupal.org/node/130944#comment-762483

I would be very grateful for any help.

Comment: Do you have a URL we can look at?

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would do it (but I'm rather new to this, so maybe your approach is better)...

```
function mythemename_preprocess_page(&$vars, $hook) {
  if (arg(0) == 'years') {
    drupal_add_css(path_to_theme().'/css/years.css');
  }
}
```

Comment: The stylesheet links have already been rendered when the *_preprocess_page() functions get called. As far as i know the only way to use your code it is to make custom module because modules renders earlier. But i dont want module.
I solved my problem by creating separate blocks for each type of page.

Comment: Cool - glad you found a solution. For the record, you can specify group and weight by doing something like this... 
function mythemename_preprocess_page(&$vars, $hook) {
  if (arg(0) == 'years') {
    drupal_add_css(path_to_theme().'/css/years.css', array(
 'group' => CSS_THEME,
 'weight' => '100',)
 );
  }
}

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest doing this with pure CSS selectors.

I'm pretty sure you can do something like this:

`/* Hides the link text. */`

a[href*="find_this_part_of_URL"] {

display: none;

}

I suggest you do NOT hide page content with this CSS, as it is bad for search engine optimization, but if you honestly can't get the theme to cover up a link, so you can focus on fixing the theme hook, use the above code.